# Symfony2: FOSUserBundle - Single firewall, multiple login forms/entry points

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

I've got a symfony2 application working with a single firewall configured with FOSUserBundle to handle the backend user persistency. This is working wonderfully.

However, I want to have more than just 1 login form/page. I need the 'standard' /login page that is used by the firewall, but I also want to embed forms in other pages for more convenient login access.

For example, on a page /booking/require_login, I tried embedding the login form template from FOSUserBundle, which is easy enough. I set **_target_path** to forward on any successful attempts which is working nicely. However, if it's an unsuccessful attempt to login, I get redirected back to the standard /login form instead of remaining on my /booking/require_login page to render with appropriate errors. I see that there's a **failure_path** parameter but this appears to be something global rather than something you can pass around as a parameter like **_target_path**.

It feels like I'm probably pushing a hacky approach further than it can go.

I don't need a separate firewall it's just an alternative way of accessing the same login with the same set of restrictions.

Can anyone offer any pointers to a clean (or easy!) approach?

Answer (score 2):

You can inject failure handler (implement `AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface`), where you can create a redirect based on the Request data (e.g. redirect to url based on failure_path post parameter).

And it is super easy to inject it, you just need to create a service called `security.authentication.failure_handler` in your DIC configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I found a workaround a while ago but this seems like a much better solution, i'll give it a try :)